# Way to include js library using magento admin

Tags: magento-1.8, xml

Is there any way to include js library on all magento product view and list pages using magento admin ?

Comment: why you need to add using magento admin, instead add it through XML

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i have made a custom plugin and i am trying not to add design folder in it. and also that js will be third party and will be included from another server. i hope i am clear.

Comment: Why would you not want to add a design folder??

Comment: because i dont need it. do you think should i need design folder for this only? if yes, can you please advise me how?

Answer (score 1):

one way you can add js library

1) add field dropdown with (yes/no) in magento configuration with your js file name;

2) then add js file into your xml file
like this

```
<reference name="head" ifconfig="your/config/value/yes">
        <action method="addJs"><script>folder/file.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Pankaj, it will be a part of plugin and i dont want customer to do this all. any other alternative using custom layout xml of magento admin?

Answer (score 0):

There is a textarea where you can put JS/CSS which is rendered into every page:

```
Admin > Configuration > Design >  Head HTML, Header and Footer
```